Android Studio virtual device doesn't load
I've been trying to run a virtual device in Android Studio but it just says "starting up" or "Waiting for target device to come online" and doesn't load. I've already tried many things to fix it in Android Studio like cold boot, wipe data, software graphics and reinstalling.
I tried to run it using the command line with every graphics option but none worked. Here's the output (some parts cut). The last 2 lines keep repeating until I stop it. How do I fix this?
PS C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> .\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_5_API_27 -verbose -debug-all -show-kernel
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.4.db, detection is enabled for process: 10436
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.1.4.0 (build_id 11672324) (CL:N/A)
DEBUG   | Current emulator version 35.1.4 is the same as the required version 35.1.4.
INFO    | Found AVD name 'Pixel_5_API_27'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86
INFO    | argv[0]: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator'
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\
INFO    | emuDirName: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator'
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\
INFO    | Probing for C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
INFO    | try dir C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_swiftshader'
INFO    | Quoted param: [C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-avd]
INFO    | Quoted param: [Pixel_5_API_27]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-verbose]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-debug-all]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-show-kernel]
DEBUG   | emulator: Running :C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[00] = "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_5_API_27"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[04] = "-debug-all"
DEBUG   | qemu backend: argv[05] = "-show-kernel"
DEBUG   | Concatenated backend parameters:  C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -avd Pixel_5_API_27 -verbose -debug-all -show-kernel
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.4.db, detection is enabled for process: 16720
I0410 23:25:41.800709    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1621] Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
D0410 23:25:41.801478    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1790] autoconfig: -skin pixel_5
D0410 23:25:41.801531    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1796] autoconfig: -skindir C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\
I0410 23:25:41.802325    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:112] Line 1: Skipped comment line.
I0410 23:25:41.802391    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:112] Line 2: Skipped comment line.
.
.
.
I0410 23:25:41.807203    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:112] Line 102: Skipped comment line.
.
.
.
I0410 23:25:41.823021    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:112] Line 474: Skipped comment line.
I0410 23:25:41.823068    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:112] Line 475: Skipped comment line.
D0410 23:25:41.835412   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3293] querying file version info API...
D0410 23:25:41.835501   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3301] found kernelbase.dll
D0410 23:25:41.835599   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3309] GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
D0410 23:25:41.835696   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3318] GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
D0410 23:25:41.835791   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3348] VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
D0410 23:25:41.836184   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3374] queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
D0410 23:25:41.837183   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3293] querying file version info API...
D0410 23:25:41.837549   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3374] queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
D0410 23:25:41.837578   11324 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/system/System.cpp:3293] querying file version info API...
D0410 23:25:41.838063    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:593] autoconfig: -kernel C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
D0410 23:25:41.838131    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:644] Target arch = 'x86'
D0410 23:25:41.838161    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:647] Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
D0410 23:25:41.838234    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:699] Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
D0410 23:25:41.838261    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:716] Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
D0410 23:25:41.838330    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:727] autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
D0410 23:25:41.838385    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:846] Using initial system image: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\system.img
D0410 23:25:41.838452    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:914] Using initial vendor image: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
D0410 23:25:41.838499    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:964] autoconfig: -data C:\Users\...\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\userdata-qemu.img
D0410 23:25:41.838536    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:991] autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\...\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\userdata.img
D0410 23:25:41.838575    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1044] autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\...\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\cache.img
D0410 23:25:41.838620    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1117] autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\...\.android\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\sdcard.img
D0410 23:25:41.838657    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1286] Physical RAM size: 2048MB
D0410 23:25:41.838683    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1340] System image is read only
I0410 23:25:41.842457    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/network/Dns.cpp:216] IPv4 server found: ...
I0410 23:25:41.843833    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/network/Dns.cpp:282] Ignore IPv6 address: ...
.
.
.
I0410 23:25:41.844111    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/network/Dns.cpp:282] Ignore IPv6 address: ...
D0410 23:25:41.844111    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/utils/src/android/utils/dns.cpp:114] Found 1 DNS servers:
D0410 23:25:41.844151    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/utils/src/android/utils/dns.cpp:117]   ...
D0410 23:25:41.844552    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-window/src/android/skin/...-config.c:379] trying to load skin file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\\pixel_5\layout'
I0410 23:25:41.844755    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/snapshot/interface.cpp:133] Found invalid RAM file. Deleting snapshot.
W0410 23:25:41.844947    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu-base/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:190] Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\...\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
D0410 23:25:41.845210    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1414] CPU Acceleration: working
D0410 23:25:41.845238    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1415] CPU Acceleration status: AEHD (version 2.2) is installed and usable.
D0410 23:25:41.845265    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-emu/android/main-common.c:1428] handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
D0410 23:25:41.845584    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/emulation/android_qemud.cpp:484] Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
D0410 23:25:41.845623    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/boot-properties.c:398] registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
D0410 23:25:41.845650    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/boot-properties.c:122] Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=*:V androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
D0410 23:25:41.845681    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/boot-properties.c:122] Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
W0410 23:25:41.845708    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/feature/src/android/featurecontrol/FeatureControlImpl.cpp:397] FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
D0410 23:25:41.845778    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:244] skin_winsys_get_monitor_rect: begin
D0410 23:25:41.845819    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:252] skin_winsys_get_monitor_rect: Begin calling platform specific display queries.
D0410 23:25:41.845856    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:254] skin_winsys_get_monitor_rect: Windows: GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
D0410 23:25:41.845885    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:256] skin_winsys_get_monitor_rect: Windows: GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
D0410 23:25:41.845906    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:302] skin_winsys_get_monitor_rect: (0,0) 1920x1080
D0410 23:25:41.846201    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:682] Qt lib path: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
D0410 23:25:41.846244    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:683] Qt plugin path: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
I0410 23:25:41.852513    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/QtLogger.cpp:47] Critical:
I0410 23:25:41.853474    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/QtLogger.cpp:47] Warning:
I0410 23:25:42.049227    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/QtLogger.cpp:47] Warning:  (6x)
D0410 23:25:42.049223    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/emulator-qt-window.cpp:1504] setFrameAlways: kEventScreenChanged
D0410 23:25:42.049624    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/emulator-qt-window.cpp:1779] slot_getScreenDimensions: begin
D0410 23:25:42.049655    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/emulator-qt-window.cpp:1783] slot_getScreenDimensions: Getting screen geometry
D0410 23:25:42.049683    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/emulator-qt-window.cpp:1788] Can't get screen geometry. Window is off screen.
D0410 23:25:42.049716    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/emulator-qt-window.cpp:362] createSkinEventScreenChanged: x=0 y=0 w=1920 h=1080 dpr=1.000000
D0410 23:25:42.068499    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:527] skin_winsys_set_window_icon
D0410 23:25:42.068636    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/surface-qt.cpp:122] skin_surface_create_from_file C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\\pixel_5\\back.webp w 1211 h 2474id 0
D0410 23:25:42.068661    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/surface-qt.cpp:68] skin_surface_width 1211
D0410 23:25:42.068686    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/surface-qt.cpp:50] skin_surface_height 0
D0410 23:25:42.068720    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/emulation/android_qemud.cpp:484] Registered QEMUD service hw-control
D0410 23:25:42.068746    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/hardware/src/android/hw-control.cpp:296] android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
D0410 23:25:42.068834    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:471] skin_winsys_get_preferred_gles_backend
D0410 23:25:42.068871    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:486] skin_winsys_get_preferred_gles_apilevel
library_mode swiftshader_indirect gpu mode swiftshader_indirect
D0410 23:25:42.123473    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-ui-qt/src/android/skin/qt/winsys-qt.cpp:486] skin_winsys_get_preferred_gles_apilevel
D0410 23:25:42.123470    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-gl-init/src/android/opengl/emugl_config.cpp:324] emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Successfully created vulkan instance
D0410 23:25:42.123964    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-gl-init/src/android/opengl/emugl_config.cpp:336] emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Physical devices count is 2
I0410 23:25:42.124217    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-gl-init/src/android/opengl/emugl_config.cpp:363] emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Found Hardware gpu 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070' supporting vulkan api 1.3.277
I0410 23:25:42.124257    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-gl-init/src/android/opengl/emugl_config.cpp:363] emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Found Hardware gpu 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 770' supporting vulkan api 1.3.250
I0410 23:25:42.124293    3908 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/android-ui/modules/aemu-gl-init/src/android/opengl/emugl_config.cpp:379] emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Using gpu 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070' for vulkan support
D0410 23:25:42.850169   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:52] sending '$GPGGA,152542,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
D0410 23:25:42.850873   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:55] missing GPS channel, ignored
D0410 23:25:42.851017   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:52] sending '$GPRMC,152542,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,100424,0.0,W*47'
D0410 23:25:42.851157   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:55] missing GPS channel, ignored
D0410 23:25:43.855063   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:52] sending '$GPGGA,152543,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
D0410 23:25:43.856495   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:55] missing GPS channel, ignored
D0410 23:25:43.856803   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:52] sending '$GPRMC,152543,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,100424,0.0,W*47'
D0410 23:25:43.857022   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:55] missing GPS channel, ignored
D0410 23:25:44.869908   20072 C:/buildbot/src/android/emu-35-1-release/external/qemu/android/emu/gps/src/android/gps.cpp:52] sending '$GPGGA,152544,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'


Not sure if it's the issue here, but I've seen emulators fail to start up properly when I had an outdated version of the emulator.  Ensure that you're on the latest emulator version, and if not, see if updating fixes it.

My android studio updated my emulator today to 35.1.4 and none of my virtual devices worked (they were fine yesterday). I manually downgraded to 34.1.20 following the instructions here and now it's working again: https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Version 34.1.20 didn't work. But version 33.1.24 did.
